# Export Android Library that depends on an App Engine Module

Tags: android, google-app-engine, module, classloader

I'd like to export an Android library module (`module A`) that depends on App Engine Module (`module B`).

In a new project with an app module (`module C`), I imported the `module A` importing the `.aar` file and the `module B` importing `moduleB/build/libs/moduleB-android-endpoints.jar`. Then I added `module A` and `module B` as dependencies of `module C` in the `module C`'s gradle file.

I can compile without errors, but when I run `module C` app seems that the `module B` classes aren't in runtime classpath.

Some hint on how solve the problem?

This is the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: moduleB.backend.registration.Registration$Builder
```

Answer (score 1):

Please go through following steps. It will solve your problem

1) Build module B and copy jar file.
2) Add module B jar (moduleB-android-endpoints.jar) into libs folder of        module A.
3) Open module A app gradle file and add following code inside dependencies directory.

```
compile files('moduleB-android-endpoints.jar')
```

4) Synchronize module A and build. It will generate aar of module A.
5) Open module C and add aar file generated by module A into libs folder of module C.
6) Add following lines to module C app gradle file.

```
dependencies {    
   compile(name:'module A aar file name', ext:'aar')
}
repositories{
   flatDir{
      dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

7) Sync and Rebuild module C. It will work

Comment: I followed all your steps but it doesn't work for me. The result is the same than before. I can build and access Registration.Builder class from Module C but not at runtime (generate the same error)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved adding these lines to the `module C`'s gradle file:

```
compile ('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.17.0-rc') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
compile ('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.17.0-rc') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
```

It was a problem related to inner Builder classes created automatically inside `module B`. They missed these dependences.